# Get set number radius of characters around substring

Tags: python, find, substring

In Python, how would I get a certain number of characters around a substring?

For example, here's my string:

```
string='Mad Max: Fury Road'
```

Let's say I wanted to add four characters away from `'ax: Fur'`, on both sides, into the output, so it would be `'ad Max: Fury Ro'`.

If the substring to look for was `'Fury Road'` in `string`, then the output would be `'ax: Fury Road'`, and it would ignore that there's nothing to add on the right side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`str.partition`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition) comes in really handy here:

```
def get_sub(string, sub, length):
    before, search, after = string.partition(sub)
    if not search:
        raise ValueError("substring not found")
    return before[-length:] + sub + after[:length]
```

You could also just return `before` in the `if` statement instead of raising a `ValueError`.  That would return the string unchanged.  Usage:

```
print(get_sub("Mad Max: Fury Road", "Fury Road", 4))
#ax: Fury Road
print(get_sub("Mad Max: Fury Road", "Fu", 4))
#ax: Fury R
```

Comment: you could also do `before,middle,after = ...` instead of `parts = ...` then get the elements of `parts`, would be a little easier to read and run slightly faster.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen: Excellent suggestion.  Implemented.

Answer (score 0):

you could also get the string before and after the substring with `.split()` then return parts of both:

```
def get_sub_and_surrounding(string,sub,length):
    before,after = string.split(sub,1) #limit to only one split
    return before[-length:] + sub + after[:length]
```

it is worth noting that in this case if `sub` is not actually a substring then the first line will raise a `ValueError`

but you can get the exact indexes for splitting it up like this:

```
def get_sub_and_surrounding(string,sub,length):
    i_start = string.index(sub) #index of the start of the substring
    i_end = i_start + len(sub) #index of the end of the substring (one after)

    my_start = max(0, i_start -length)
    # ^prevents use of negative indices from counting
    # from the end of the string by accident

    my_end = min(len(string), i_end+length) #this part isn't actually necessary, "a"[:100] just goes to the end of the string

    return string[my_start : my_end]
```

In this case `string.index(sub)` will raise a `ValueError` if sub is not in string.